# Bluetooth performance worse after Yosemite update

Tags: audio, macos, bluetooth, trackpad, headphones

I have a bluetooth trackpad and a pair of bluetooth headphones and ever since I upgraded  to Yosemite I've been having problems with both.

The trackpad fails to re-connect after the laptop wakes up more often that it before as do the headphones, on top of that the headphones are a lot choppier, to the point I can't listen. When connected to my phone they work flawlessly.

I'd unpaired & re-paired both devices & also removed them by deleting them from the .plist file directly, this improved things for a few days, but now it's back to the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a bug in Yosemite. I have this issue and other people have it also.

I think we can just wait until it is fixed or return to Mavericks. I have tried resetting SMC and some other "fixes" from the internet without success.

[OS 10.10.1 Yosemite has Bluetooth Audio Delay (lag, latency)](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6733167)

Answer (score 0):

As I noted on the response to this question: [Yosemite bluetooth audio is choppy/skips](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167245/yosemite-bluetooth-audio-is-choppy-skips), the XCode bluetooth explorer makes available some audio options (tools..audio options) that let you tune the quality of the audio via bluetooth.

You need to install xcode, then install the hardwareIO extensions to Xcode.