# Bluetooth audio is choppy / stuttering on Macbook Pro (Mojave) but not iPhone

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, audio, mojave, bluetooth

Audio playing from my Macbook Pro (Late 2016 15" w/ Touch Bar, OS v10.14.6) to my true wireless earbuds (Jabra Elite 75t) is often choppy / stuttering. The problem seems to be with the Macbook because audio playing from my iPhone 8 Plus to the Jabra earbuds never stutters. I can't upgrade from Mojave to Catalina because I use some legacy software.

Things I've tried:

- Unpair/re-pair
- Bluetooth menu -> Debug - Reset the bluetooth module
- Reset PRAM
- Disconnect wifi
- Disconnect iPhone <-> Jabra connection
- Change Sound settings for Input to Internal Microphone rather than Jabra
- Set AirDrop to be discoverable by no one
- Jump between wifi 2.4Ghz and 5Ghz and change channels
- Jabra firmware upgrade
- Play audio from different apps (Spotify, VLC, Youtube on Chrome, etc.)
- Try [these commands](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/179209/366929) (in particular the ones under EDIT 3 and EDIT 4) for improving the power/bandwidth for the bluetooth module.
- Try the "Force AptX" option [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PkBwuXwhysY), that made my sound much worse.

When I open Console.app and filter for faults or errors plus the term "bluetooth," all I see is the error message "CoreBluetooth isn't advertising for this client type" from process "wirelessproxd"; not sure what that's about, maybe something to do with AirDrop.

What else should I try?

Many thanks

Comment: Does the MacBook play the audio without the glitches through a wired set of earbuds/headphones?

Comment: Yes audio plays just fine through wired earbuds and headphones.

Comment: Luke, I'm having the same problem: Jabra 75t elite mic audio used to work perfectly with macbook pro 2013. Now the mic audio stutters and sounds robotic with a macbook pro 2020. Mic audio is fine and pristine with pixel 3. Very surprising to me. Here's a very useful discussion on Reddit about the same issue, with more insights but no solutions: https://www.reddit.com/r/Jabra/comments/f9bnfx/elite_active_75t_absolute_garbage_with_mac/

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [support documents](https://www.jabra.com/supportpages/jabra-elite-65t-iet-6500/100-99000000-02/faq/Can-I-pair-my-Jabra-Bluetooth-device-with-a-computer#/) at Jabra, the earbuds aren't designed for use with a computer:

*No, we do not recommend you pair your Jabra Bluetooth device directly with a computer. Jabra Bluetooth headsets are optimized to be used with other Bluetooth devices, such as, smartphones or tablets. They are not optimized to be used directly with a computer. We cannot guarantee device performance or provide support for performance problems that may result from this.
If you choose to pair your Jabra Bluetooth device with a computer, it could work for audio streaming, but not for call control, which is not supported by many computers. Also, audio quality could vary depending on the model of the computer.*

Comment: Wow, that is surprising! Technically that document is for the 65t not the 75t, but I agree it's probably true for the 75t as well. It's a bummer the WireCutter review for the Jabra 75t didn't mention this; they seem to imply pairing with a laptop should work fine.

This might help explain why I'm having a problem, but I'll keep the question open for now in case someone can recommend steps that might improve the audio reliability even if pairing with a laptop might not be officially supported by Jabra.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and tried tons of different solutions. After a lot of tries, this solved it:

Go to:  → System Preferences → General and uncheck the option “Allow Handoff between this Mac and your iCloud devices.”

Comment: That worked for me just now for a couple of different sets of bluetooth earbuds, but I have no idea why. Thanks for sharing it.

Answer (score 1):

I had this happen even with Apple made headphones. In my case the problem was that I was connecting more than 3 devices to my Mac through Bluetooth, and it seems that it can’t properly handle more than 3 devices.