# Bluetooth headphones/speakers connect for a second and disconnect immediately

Tags: macos, mac, audio, bluetooth, headphones

I was having the issue where the bluetooth audio was stuttering. I was trying a variety of solutions but wasn't able to solve it. I tried following this answer [Yosemite bluetooth audio is choppy/skips](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/167245/yosemite-bluetooth-audio-is-choppy-skips?newreg=53c0cf1cc6cd40b89825698e5ec6c09a)

and ran the two commands to kill coreaudiod and bluetoothaudiod and am having the above mentioned problem ever since since. The headphones connect for a second and disconnect immediately. I tried rebooting the device multiple times, resetting the bluetooth module and deleting the plist file but it is still not working.

I tried safe mode, that did not work either.

Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4 MacBook Pro 13 inch 2014 version.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting the Mac?

Comment: macOS version?  Mac model?  Bluetooth device?

Comment: Yes I have tried rebooting multiple times. Also tried resetting the bluetooth module and deleting the plist file. Mac OS Catalina 10.15.4 MacBook Pro 13 inch 2014 version.

Comment: Try booting in Safe Mode so *only* Apple kexts get loaded.  Let's see if the problem clears up.

Comment: I tried safe mode, that did not worked either.